# How to do the difference from yyyy/mm using month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a column called `[date]` and the data in that column is something like this:

```
[date]

2011/01
2011/02
2011/03
2011/04
2011/05
2011/06
2011/07
2011/08
2011/09
2011/10
```

My full scenario is that I have created a column named `[date]` and I am dumping the data to that column from another column called `[fiscal_month]` (both are from same table).

I have to retrieve the latest 9 months data from that `[date]` column and I have written this code:

```
SELECT TOP 9 REPLACE (P.[Fiscal Month],'M','/') as [date],
      P.[Fiscal Month] AS [Fiscal Month] FROM [OR].[Report].[SD_P] P 
WHERE [date] <= CONVERT(char(7), GETDATE(), 111) ORDER BY [date] DESC
```

The `[fiscal_month]` column is VARCHAR(100).

The data in the `[fiscal_month]` column is something like this:

```
2011M01,2011M02, 2011M03, 2011M04, 2011M05
```

etc

**Update:**

I altered the `[date]` column and I have assigned the `datetime` datatype for that column and then I select into it with the replacement of 'M' from the other column with '/' to get the 9 months latest data..

Comment: recent from end of the last month..

Comment: I'm assuming that the data type of the column varchar as opposed to datetime?

Comment: Actually My full scenario is I have created a [date] column and I dumping the data to that [date] column from another column called [fiscal_month] (both are from same table). And I have to retrieve the latest 9 months data from that [date] column and I have written this code                    SELECT TOP 9 REPLACE (P.[Fiscal Month],'M','/') as [date],P.[Fiscal Month] AS [Fiscal Month]
FROM [OR].[Report].[SD_P] P
WHERE [date] <= CONVERT(char(7), GETDATE(), 111)
ORDER BY [date] DESC       and the fiscal_month COLUMN IS VARCHAR(100). i GUESS THE PROBLEM IN THAT COLUMN..

Comment: Never store dates in a varchar column. This is a very poor practice and is why you have to go to rediclous lengths to do date math.

Comment: -1 for an incomplete and misleading question

Comment: I donno..I am just new to sql server and Just joined the company and they had already create that table...But the data in the fiscal_month column is something like this 2011M01,2011M02,  2011M03, 2011M04, 2011M05,etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the `date` column is actually stored as text. If that's the case, the easiest solution is to convert it to a datetime and then do your comparison:

```
Select ...
From MyTable
Where Cast(Replace([Date],'/','') + '01' As DateTime)
    > DateAdd(m, -9
         , DateAdd(d
             , -Day(GetDate())
             , DateAdd(d, DateDiff(d, 0, GetDate() ), 0)))
```

The following snippet is used to strip the time portion from today's date:

```
DateAdd( d, DateDiff(d, 0, GetDate() ), 0 )
```

---

**Update**

Given your addition, you only need a small change the query above:

```
Select ...
From MyTable
Where Cast(Replace([Date],'M','') + '01' As DateTime)
    > DateAdd(m, -9
         , DateAdd(d
             , -Day(GetDate())
             , DateAdd(d, DateDiff(d, 0, GetDate() ), 0)))
```

---

**Update**

Given that you have now converted your `date` column to `datetime`, you can simplify your query:

```
Select ...
From MyTable
Where [Date] > DateAdd(m, -9, DateAdd(d
                               , -Day(GetDate())
                               , DateAdd(d, DateDiff(d, 0, GetDate() ), 0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TOP 9 [date]
FROM Mytable
WHERE [date] <= CONVERT(char(7),DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), -1), 111)
ORDER BY [date] DESC
```

Comment: I guess it will give you the top 9 rows data only. But I would like to find out the latest or recent 9 months data...Is this will give the output What I want..Just give me few minutes Let me test it once...Though thanks for giving me so quick response..

Comment: It is giving me this error: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What type is date column then?

Comment: I am not blaming that you query is wrong and I am just asking you guys where could be the error exists..

Comment: It can't be datetime with yyyy/mm Ask a proper and correct question with complete information

Comment: altered that column I have put the datetime datatype for that column and then I am select into it with the replacement of 'M'from the other column with '/' to get the 9 months latest data...